# Formula to calculate amounts based based on a specific category

Tags: worksheet-function

I am working on my personal budget and need a formula that calculates the amounts for each category and sticks them in a relevant cell in a different tab. I have a test spreadsheet with the example I'm talking about.

I have a tab that has 3 columns: category, budget, Actuals. on the other tab, i list my daily entries/expenses. What i want is a formulas that sums the amounts of the same category and enters that amount in the appropriate row/category for my actuals column in the other tab

Comment: Look into [`SUMIFS()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: it worked...thank you